# Instance method call Dispose

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dispose, idisposable

Is correct that a public method calls the Dispose of IDisposable in the same class?

E.g.

```
public class Worker : IDisposable
{
    public void Close()
    {
       SendCloseCommand();
       Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       ////other resources release
    }

    private void SendCloseCommand()
    {
    }
}
```

Another thing about disposable pattern:
If the Close should be always called, is better that is called from the Dispose method or not?

If not, I should put the usage of the *Worker* class in a try/catch/finally everywhere, to call the Close. Right?

The correct design should instead be?

```
public class Worker : IDisposable
{
    public void Close()
    {
       SendCloseCommand();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       Close();
       ////other resources release
    }

    private void SendCloseCommand()
    {
        ////other stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [Microsoft implementation for `StreamReader`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs), `Dispose` gets called from `Close`,

```
public override void Close()
{
    Dispose(true);
}
```

and also the implementation for `Dispose` closes the stream as well by calling `Close` of base `Stream`.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    // Dispose of our resources if this StreamReader is closable.
    // Note that Console.In should be left open.
    try {
        // Note that Stream.Close() can potentially throw here. So we need to 
        // ensure cleaning up internal resources, inside the finally block.  
        if (!LeaveOpen && disposing && (stream != null))
            stream.Close();
    }
    finally {
        if (!LeaveOpen && (stream != null)) {
            stream = null;
            encoding = null;
            decoder = null;
            byteBuffer = null;
            charBuffer = null;
            charPos = 0;
            charLen = 0;
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

In your class implementation, I would call the `Dispose` from your `Close` method as you are doing in your first code snippet. In `Dispose`, I would check for `Worker` status, if it is not closed then close it using `SendCloseCommand`, and then release resources.

```
public void Dispose()
{
   if(this.Status != Closed) // check if it is not already closed
     {
         SendCloseCommand();
     }

   ////other resources release
}
```

This will ensure your resources disposal, even if your class is used with `using` statement, or if any one calls `Close` manually.

Just remember to check status of your `Worker` object, before issuing Close Command.

Comment: Infact, I agree with your example, I don't want to fill the code with try/catch/finally instead simply use the using statement.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has some suggestions about having a `Close` method on a class implementing `IDisposable`. It is part of the [Dispose Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) guidelines:

> **CONSIDER** providing method `Close()`, in addition to the `Dispose()`, if close is standard terminology in the area.
>
> When doing so, it is important that you make the `Close` implementation identical to `Dispose` and consider implementing the `IDisposable.Dispose` method explicitly.

```
public class Stream : IDisposable {
    IDisposable.Dispose(){
        Close();
    }
    public void Close(){
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

So Microsofts suggestion is to hide `Dispose` and let it call `Close` to do the actual cleanup. Also, remember the guideline about multiple calls to `Dispose`:

> **DO** allow the `Dispose(bool)` method to be called more than once. The method might choose to do nothing after the first call.

Following these guidelines makes your code consistent with the .NET library and you will avoid any confusion about if your class should be closed or disposed for proper cleanup.